How do I make my modal bottom sheet + Draggable scrollable sheet take up 3/4 of the screen instead of full screen?
When creating my modal bottom sheet, I started with the sheet at around half the screen's size. I looked around and wanted to show a more full screen, but still enable the UI to show the drag handle.
Right now, my modal bottom sheet is full screen, and this is the code:
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  isDismissible: true,
  showDragHandle: true,
  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(15)),
  ),
  builder: (context) => DraggableScrollableSheet(
    initialChildSize: 1,
    builder: (context, scrollController) => MyWidget()
  ),
),

Which again, gets me full screen. However, I want my bottom sheet to be just under full screen, kind of like this where you can see the drag handle:

is there a way to do this? I've tried a few options like playing around with the initialChildSize of the DraggableScrollableSheet but couldn't get it close; I'm either stuck at half height or full screen.

have you tried to wrap that DraggableSheet with a fixed height widget like SizedBox and giving it 0.75 of screen height!

@A-E I can't believe I didn't think about that lol. I'm using Sizer and set my height to 75.h and that worked. If you put this in an answer I'll mark it as answered. thank you!!!

Wrap the DraggableScrollableSheet with an Intrinsic height widget like SizedBox or a Container with a 0.75 of screen height to force fixed height:
 builder: (context) =>SizedBox(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.75,
  child:  DraggableScrollableSheet(
    initialChildSize: 1,
    builder: (context, scrollController) => MyWidget()
  ),
 ),

